# Simple generic double buffer pattern

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety, generics

I wrote a small generic implementation of a simple generic double buffer pattern, and I was wondering if it's actually thread safe or can be improved in any way.

Note: The specific part that I'm worrying about thread safety is the `Swap()` function.

```
/// <summary>
///     Simple generic double buffer implementation class
/// </summary>
public class DoubleBuffer<T> where T : class
{
    private T _current;

    public DoubleBuffer(T current, T next)
    {
        _current = current;
        Next = next;
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Next buffer waiting in line (no active usage should be here)
    /// </summary>
    public T Next { get; private set; }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Currently active buffer (active usage should be here)
    /// </summary>
    public T Current
    {
        get { return _current; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Swaps between the buffers
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>Returns the buffer previously used before the swap</returns>
    public T Swap()
    {
        var swappedBuffer = _current;
        Interlocked.Exchange(ref _current, Next);
        Next = swappedBuffer;
        return swappedBuffer;
    }
}
```

Comment: *"Simple generic double buffer pattern"* - Now that's a mouthful.

Comment: @EthanBierlein it's a very useful pattern for multi threaded systems :)

Comment: How is this class supposed to be used? You will set `current` and `next` once, inside the constructor, and then use `Swap` many times to swap them? And multiple threads can call `Swap` simultaneously? I suppose you can only have two active threads at a single time using this? tl;dr: use a simple `lock` to swap these two variables, performance difference will be negligible, but you will get correctness, which is far more important. Also, exposing `Current` and `Next` and `Swap` publicly doesn't seem like a good idea, I would rethink how you want this class to be used.

Comment: @Groo - we use it as a "write only" buffer (list, queue, dictionary, etc) and a "read only" buffer, i.e. collecting metrics from a multi threaded environment, and periodically dumping them out.

And since this pattern requires to have access both to the write and read buffer, we had to keep them public.

A classic example of the double buffer design pattern usage is how video cards prevent screen tearing from occurring.

Comment: Updates to the video frame buffer are done a single thread, the one which also swaps the buffer, so it's not an analogy you should stick to too closely. Your updated code is giving a false sense of security, because exposing these two buffers as public properties makes no guarantees about which one is being read/written to at any given moment. Any access to those properties is unsynchronized with the swap procedure, and can happen at any time inside the swap method. Also, `TryEnter` with timeout is unnecessary, swapping these properties only takes a couple of instructions.

Comment: @groo - I never said there are writes to the same video buffer from multiple threads, but for the sake of simplicity, that there are multiple threads accessing the buffer (i.e. video card writing, computer screen reading), and that's a classic example of double buffering. Regarding the public accessors I agree that it's not well designed - however what would you suggest in order to improve the encapsulation of this class? And regarding `TryEnter` - if I'm not mistaken `lock()` is compiled to use `Montior`, and using `TryEnter` is an office standard to prevent dead-locks

Comment: I'm currently thinking of maybe removing the public accessors to T, and change T to inherit from an interface (which exposes write/read functions), and then change the class to expose 3 public methods, `Swap()`, `Read()`, and `Write()`

Comment: @Ron-It depends on what you are trying to achieve. I'm not sure you can even write a thread-safe double buffer class if you expose the Swap method. However, you can implement code that will "behave" with your particular implementation if certain conventions are followed, but that would be a stretch to call it thread-safe. You could put a wrapper around your double buffer which is more promising. Perhaps if you give a very explicit example of something you are trying to achieve then you can get some better answers. I will be very surprised if double buffering ends up being a good solution.

Comment: @Dunk - One example is a concurrent queue where one thread reads from the queue, and another thread needs to populate it; we us the double buffer to keep the read queue buffer highly available as we enqueue thousands of items into the write buffer, and then once the write buffer is full we simply swap references between the read/write buffers. We now have another place we want to use this pattern, and I wanted to make it generic so we don't duplicate code, and allow easy future use of this pattern.

Comment: @Ron: If you believe you need higher throughput than you would get with a lockless FIFO (e.g. `ConcurrentQueue<T>`) then it will work as long as your writer thread is controlling the swapping, and if you ensure that reader cannot hold a reference to a writer buffer. This means that writer would have to write items, stop writing, swap, and then continue writing into a new buffer. If you only have two buffers, and reader is still reading the previous one in the moment writer swaps them, then you also break thread safety. I.e., writer should always allocate a new buffer after swapping.

Comment: @Ron: I am presuming your current code presumes that reader will always finish reading before the next swap. So, apart from always allocating (or alternatively, using a pool), there is also an alternative where your writer always takes a lock while it's writing to a buffer. If there is no contention, locks are very cheap and you would most likely have better throughput on average than a `ConcurrentQueue<T>` (presuming you write several items inside a lock, and reader only rarely locks for swapping). In that case, swapping would be safe, as you would be sure that you only swap between writes.

Comment: @Ron-What you really need is a thread priority inversion mutex/semaphore protecting a single queue. Real-time operating systems tend to have these standard. I don't think Windows has them but if you look online there's many different ways to simulate the same type of behavior. I think you are missing the implicit assumption that with double buffering it is ok to drop a buffer every now and then. e.g. What happens when the read buffer hasn't been processed but the write buffer is full? In your example, it doesn't seem like swapping buffers and losing data would be a desirable feature.

Answer (score 12):

Please correct me if I am wrong, but isn't such scenario possible with accepted answer?

```
public T Swap()
{
    var swappedBuffer = Interlocked.Exchange(ref _current, Next); // 1
    Next = swappedBuffer; // 2
    return swappedBuffer; // 3
}
```

And it goes like that: (`A` and `B` denotes some object of type `T`):

```
_current = A
Next = B

Thread 1 executes Line 1: 
swappedBuffer = A
_current = B
Next = B

Thread 2 executes Line 1:
swappedBuffer = B
_current = B
Next = B

Thread 1 executes Line 2:
Next = A

Thread 2 executes Line 2:
Next = B
```

Now both `_current` and `Next` are references to B.

Comment: Good call, I think wrapping the code in Swap with a lock would solve it:
`public T Swap()
        {
            if (!Monitor.TryEnter(_lockObject, new TimeSpan(0, 0, 2)))
            {
                throw new Exception("Swap: Timed out waiting for lock.");
            }
            var swappedBuffer = Interlocked.Exchange(ref _writeBuffer, ReadBuffer);
            ReadBuffer = swappedBuffer;
            Monitor.Exit(_lockObject);
            return swappedBuffer;
        }`

Comment: First of all: I am not sure whether my doubts are correct. Second: I am not sure whether there is any point using Interlocked.Exchange when inside critical section.

Comment: You are correct, `Interlocked.Exchange` is only atomic with respect to one of the two variables being swapped.  To do this lock-free, you need to use a double-word compare-exchange.

Comment: Please note that with "accepted answer" I refer to answer, that is no longer available here.

Answer (score 8):

I would start by making sure everything that doesn't need to be public is hidden, and then simplify the `Swap` method to avoid race conditions.

1. Hide everything except the `Swap` method. It's not like you gain any real "safety" against incorrect usage (as everyone can cache the result of that method anyway), but at least people don't have to think twice how to use it:

   ```
   // we probably won't need the T : class constraint
   public class DoubleBuffer<T>
   {
       private T _current;
       private T _next;

       public DoubleBuffer(T current, T next)
       {
           _current = current;
           _next = next;
       }

       public T Swap()
       {
            // swap and return previous value
       }
   }
   ```
2. Preferably, use a simple `lock` to ensure thread safety. .NET `lock` (i.e. `Monitor`) is pretty efficient for short blocks like this. If there is no contention, it's practically free. It also spinlocks for several cycles before it enters kernel mode, meaning that short blocks like this should never put the thread to sleep:

   ```
   // this is a no-brainer, simple and without race conditions
   private readonly object _lock = new object();
   public T Swap()
   {
       lock (_lock)
       {
           var previous = _current;
           _current = _next;
           _next = previous;
           return previous;
       }
   }
   ```
3. If you really want to make sure you're spinlocking, you can use a `SpinLock` instead (slightly less readable, but nothing spectacular for a method short as this):

   ```
   public T Swap()
   {
       var spinlock = new SpinLock();
       var taken = false;
       try
       {
           spinlock.Enter(ref taken);
           var previous = _current;
           _current = _next;
           _next = previous;
           return previous;
       }
       finally
       {
           if (taken)
               spinlock.Exit();
       }
   }
   ```
4. Finally, if you want to confuse your friends and code reviewers, you can go for something like this, which doesn't really swap values internally, but instead stores them inside an array and toggles the index. And since our class' interface is now simplified (only the `Swap` method), callers don't need to know out implementation details at all:

   ```
   public class DoubleBuffer<T>
   {
       private int _index = 1;
       private T[] _values = new T[2];

       public DoubleBuffer(T current, T next)
       {
           _values[0] = current;
           _values[1] = next;
       }

       public T Swap()
       {
           // note: _index will overflow after a bunch of calls,
           // but last bit will still be flipped correctly
           var i = Interlocked.Increment(ref _index);
           return _values[i & 1]; // bitwise '&' is cheaper than '%'
       }
   }
   ```
5. Which can then be slightly generalized and extended to more than just two items (we can also call it a `Pool` now, although there is no way to let callers "return" objects back to the pool):

   ```
   public class Pool<T>
   {
       private int _index = 1;
       private T[] _values;

       public Pool(params T[] values)
       {
           if (values == null)
               throw new ArgumentNullException("values cannot be null");

           if (values.Length == 0)
               throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("values cannot be empty");

           _values = (T[])values.Clone(); // @Kuba's comment
       }

       public T Swap()
       {
           var i = Interlocked.Increment(ref _index);
           return _values[mod(i, _values.Length)];
       }

       // modulo which works nice with negative values
       int mod(int x, int m)
       {
           int r = x % m;
           return r < 0 ? r + m : r;
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: It is worth noting in my opinion, that, while previous implementation hold given references forever, a array that can be passed in pt. 5 (as an alternative to listing each **param** independently) can be modified later on by external code. Maybe it should be cloned in the constructor?

Comment: Also there is probably a typo in version 4: `return _values[i & 2];`.

Comment: @Kuba: (unless I am wrong, I am pretty tired) it should be `i % 2` if using modulo, but bitwise it's `i & 1` since last bit is being flipped on each increment (and this is a cheap instruction). I have just checked and it seems to be working correctly even when `_index` overflows (that's why I added a separate `mod` method in the last case also).

Comment: Oh yes, right, sorry. :)

Comment: @Kuba: just noticed your first comment, yes, you're right, that would be a better thing to do (although if `T` is a reference type, nothing stops OP from mutating its values).

Answer (score 2):

The code is definitely not thread-safe.

I quickly see 4 or 5 ways to break the example code but here's the simplest:

```
writer1: writeBuf1 = doubleBuf.Current;
writer1: ...start writing data to writeBuf1...
   ...writer2 interrupts writer1 thread...
writer2: writeBuf2 = doubleBuf.Current;  // writeBuf1 and 2 point to same place
writer2: ...start write data to writeBuf2... // writer2 and 1 data is mixed
```

There's no reason to use double-buffering for what you described.

If you want to make the class thread-safe then you'd need a Read and Write method that extracts/writes the data from/to the buffer. The buffer needs to be protected by a lock in each method. Done.

Even if you wanted to do the double buffer scheme, you'd implement in the exact same way as the single buffer method, via Read/Write methods and locking in those methods. You have to copy the buffer data, you can't ever return direct access to the class's internal buffers if you want to create a thread-safe class unless you also pass ownership along with that buffer.

Comment: Please don't post a second answer when you wish to add details, instead edit your post with the additional info. Since this has more info in it the other one will probably be deleted.

Comment: Sorry, I thought that was what I did. I must have pushed a wrong button in the process.